# Create and write file txt

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter, console.out.writeline

How can I create and then modify writing on this file?

```
string fileName = @"C:\...\MioFile.txt";
```

In main:

```
File.CreateText(fileName);
```

Then when I would edit the file by adding text.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
sw.WriteLine("Hello"+variable);
sw.Close();
```

But the file is empty and I cannot write anything.

I would like create a file.txt and I would like for this file to always add new information every time I call it in writing mode. A kind of "log file".

Comment: If you look at the docs of the [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class you will find a lot of links that explain how to work with files

Answer (score 2):

Use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `StreamWriter`. Its simple:

```
File.AppendAllText(filename, "Hello"+variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have sw.WriteLine, But your streamwriter is called "writer". That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the "using" statements:

```cs
//full path
var fileName = @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\newFile2.txt";
//Get the stream in FileMode.Append (will create or open)
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Append))
{
    //pass the fileStream into the writer.
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("{0} => file appended", DateTime.Now);
    }//dispose writer
}//dispose fileStream
```